# What is the easiest way to add many images to Visio as shapes in a custom stencil?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

The company I work for produces hundreds of standardized icons that we can use for diagrams, mainly for making PowerPoint presentations. I wanted to start using Visio for these diagrams, because the connectors and flowchart tools are really handy and make a ton of sense for what we do.
I have created a custom stencil in Visio for this task, but I can't seem to figure out how to quickly add multiple images to the stencil. I can add one image at a time, but Visio doesn't recognize the file name, and I have to manually rename every single one. If I try to add multiple images at once, Visio doesn't seem to understand it at all, and merges them all into one shape instead of adding them discretely.

Is there a simple way to bulk-add a bunch of image files as shapes to a custom stencil? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a (commercial - but free to try out) utility to do this:

[Super Utilities for Visio](http://www.paulherber.co.uk/visio-utilities3/)

Ribbon -> SuperUtils -> Stencil -> Create Stencil from Images